# Square Connect API: How do I get the dining option e.g. "to stay" or "to go"

Tags: square-connect

I'm using the square connect API.

When I create a new order from the GUI, I see this:

[image]

It looks like there is a "Dining Options" field. Is there a way to retrieve this using the connect API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most order functionality is not currently supported (including this), however the Square team is actively working on changing that. Stay tuned!